# How to give equal space to two elements?

Tags: html, css

I am creating online test application my problem is if options are in different length means alignment was not correct.for example

1.Test Question?

a).op12 b).op234

c).op145 d).op345

Here You can see b) and d) are not align proper i know this was simple question but i am stuck in this problem.how can i use css or anything else.

mycode is

```
<div style='padding-left:1em'>a).op12 b).op234</div><br/>
<div style='padding-left:1em'>c).op145 d).op345</div>
```

if i am using separate  tag for each option means it display like

```
 a)op12
  b)op234
   c)op145
   d)op345
```

can any one give me the idea to solve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/8mdhkuz4/1/. I believe you should use `<ul></ul` for this.

Comment: Why not put each `op###` to `td`? Than if any op is longer, it will expand whole column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should use `Table` instead of `div`

```
Question
<table width="300px" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
        <td>a).op12</td><td>b).op234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a).op12</td><td>b).op234</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mdhkuz4/3/)

Comment: Yes @KVK instead of using lot of `CSS` You can use choose good structure of `HTML` according to your situation. Glad this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a wrapper div of same width for all options.

Use this code

```
<div class="opt-row"><span>a).op12</span> <span>b).op234</span></div>
<div class="opt-row"><span>c).op145</span> <span>d).op345</span></div>
```

& CSS:

```
.opt-row{padding-left:1em;}
.opt-row span{display:inline-block; width:100px;} /*Change this with accordingy */
```

Here is [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8q678ws8/)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use `<ul>` in this case, `<li>` can be easily managed with css according to your purpose.

here's an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mdhkuz4/6/)

i hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Manwal'w advice:
If you need a list, Use list.  Div is meaningless.
While using HTML - the HTML is the content, the css is for design, the js is for behavior.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            li { min-width:10em; list-style-type: lower-alpha;}
            li.odd { float:left; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol>
            <li class='odd'>op12</li>
            <li class='even'>op234</li>
            <li class='odd'>op145</li>
            <li class='even'>op345</li>

        </ol>

    </body>
</html>
```